# Sending a string through a socket using TCP

Tags: java, android, string, sockets, tcp

I am trying to send a string (and later also an image) from one Android app, to another Android app. I know that I am very close.

The code "SendString" is one Android app on one phone. And the code "AppListener" is on the other phone. "SendString" seems to be working correctly and sending the string because all of my print statements are printing.

**"SendString", which is sending a string to "AppListener":**

(the string that I am sending "applicationName" is getting passed to "SendString" from a different activity in the project)

I know this code is working because I get all the print statements in "try" and it never gets passed to the catch Exception.

```
public class SendString extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    Log.d("tag_name", "Entered AsyncTask");

    String applicationName = params[0];


    // SEND APPLICATION NAME AND ICON TO OTHER APP

    try {

        Log.d("tag_name", "TRY TO SEND STRING");
        Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.26", 1755);
        DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DOS.writeUTF(applicationName);
        Log.d("tag_name", "Application Name Sent!");
        socket.close();

    }

    catch (Exception e){

        Log.d("tag_name", "Did not send string");

    }

    return null;
}

}
```

Here is the other Android app code that is listening for a port connection, and then it should be receiving the string from "SendString".

```
public class AppListener extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {

    String msg_received = null;

    System.out.println("LISTENING FOR LAST INSTALLED APP");

    try {


        System.out.println("TRY");
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(1755);
        System.out.println("Connect to Socket and listening");
        Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();       //This is blocking. It will wait.
        System.out.println("This should print after connection");
        DataInputStream DIS = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        msg_received = DIS.readUTF();

        System.out.println("Message from server" + msg_received);

        clientSocket.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Did not connect to SendString");
    }
    System.out.println("Return Statement is Reached");
    return msg_received;
}
}
```

The problem is that it seems to be getting stuck at the line

```
Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();       //This is blocking. It will wait.
```

because I never get the print statement "this should print after connection", but I get all the print statements before that. Does anyone see what the problem is and why my AppListener activity seems to not connect to the port to receive the string, even though I know that the "SendString" app is connecting and sending the string as it should be (because I see all the print statements).

Comment: you should run your second peice of code first (it is your server).  It will wait for a client.  Now run your first peice of code (it is your client)

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I updated my question to be more clear. Maybe you could take a look. I tried testing by running the second code first "AppListener", but I am still faced with the same problem.

Comment: May I suggest that the second android is NOT listening on ip address 192.168.0.26.

Comment: @ScaryWombat So I did figure out that the string gets passed correctly when "AppListener" is connected to a Public Network. If AppListener is using a private IP address (address that starts with something in the 190's), then the string is never sent to "AppListener". Do you have any idea how I can change my code so that I can send the string to a device connected to a private Wifi network?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone see what the problem is and why my Client seems to not connect to the port to receive the string, even though I know that the server side is connecting and sending the string as it should be.

1. You have 'server' and 'client' mixed up. Clients connect: servers accept.
2. Your real server, which you described as your client, isn't accepting a connection.
3. This can only mean that your real client, which you described as your server, isn't creating one.

You must have either not executed your real client at all, or else got a `ConnectException` you haven't told us about.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my confusion! I updated my question to be more clear (I hope). So, you are saying that my server "AppListener" is not accepting a connection, which I completely agree with because this is where my code seems to get stuck and doesn't create any more print statements. It seems like my client  is making a connection because I see all the print statements including "application name sent!", and it never throws an exception. But, could it be possible that its not making a connection even though it never throws an exception?

Comment: It must be connecting to something else.

Comment: So I did figure out that the string gets passed correctly when "AppListener" is connected to a Public Network. If AppListener is using a private IP address (address that starts with something in the 190's), then the string is never sent to "AppListener". Do you have any idea how I can change my code so that I can send the string to a device connected to a private Wifi network?